# Why when I upload image to twitter sometimes it is shown on tweet list and sometimes there is "View Photo" link?

Tags: twitter

I am using twitter api  `1.1` and `statuses/update_with_media` endpoint to create tweet with photo. The problem is that sometimes on the tweet list I see this image and sometimes it there is only link `View Photo` - only when I click this link then image is shown...

It seems to depend on image itself but can't figure out how...
I have some images which are ALWAYS shown on tweet list and I have images which are NEVER shown on tweet list.

Does it have something in common with image size?

Answer (score 0):

According to twitter api documentation you can upload only 5 media in one hour if you cross this limit then you face this problem